# Dynamically generated page scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my App, I am creating the dynamic pages, in which I given the `css` property to page container as `overflow-y:auto`. all works fine,

the problem is whenever the page loads, the page height exceeds and the height of the contaienr, the `scroll` works, but the scroll bar placed in the end of page. so i am seeing the end of the content of the container instead of the top.

is there any way to sort this issue without using `script`? if so any one suggest me the correct way please?

or do I need to add any special `css` property in the container?

any one advice me the correct approach please?

**Update**
This is happening only with `Chrome` browser. ie and firefox behaves correctly.

Comment: assuming your container app has a class of container, and you are using jquery, then `$('.container').scrollTop(0)` should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try below combination

```
overflow-y:auto
position:relative
```

by adjusting position to relative your scroll bar will remains at what you want.
hope it will help for you the same way i am doing this thing its works for me

Comment: Let me try yours. But the issue I finding only with `Chrome` browser. `Firefox` and `ie` works correctly.